# controlling the behaviour of keyUp jquery event

Tags: jquery, events, keyup

i am calling a function on keyup event the problem is whenever i type in text area it shows duplicate results assume  i am typing google.com in text area it is supposed to show results for google.com it does but final result is always unexpected like goo or googl when i type with with speed in a text box

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchip').keyup(function(){
                $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "whois.php",
                    data: 'ip=' + $('#searchip').val(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#resultip').html(msg);
                    }
                }); // Ajax Call
            }); //event handler
        }); //document.ready
```

Answer (score 1):

What about debounce it a little using a timeout:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var timeout, request;
     $('#searchip').keyup(function () {
         clearTimeout(timeout);
         if(request) request.abort();
         timeout = setTimeout(function () {                 
             request = $.ajax({    
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "whois.php",
                 data: 'ip=' + $('#searchip').val(),
                 success: function (msg) {
                     $('#resultip').html(msg);                         
                 }
             }).done(function(){request = null;}); // Ajax Call
         }, 150);
     }); //event handler
 });
```

Comment: @BalintBako should not be a problem here, i'll test it

Comment: Debounce time can be adjusted, however he's using .html() so results returned are messed up and there's potentially an entirely separate problem on the back-end as well :)

Comment: @DamyanPetev ya because aborting request won't have any effect server side, that's true

Comment: dosn't work for me please check this    http://s10.postimg.org/5qdopsvm1/Capture.png

Comment: Have you a link to test it instead of a picture?

Comment: setting timeout to 1000 works but  unfortunately this is not a solution for me i want instant results without any duplicacy like you get on this website http://instantdomainsearch.com/